# Record and edit two videos at same time

Tags: video

I have a need to record a lecture. I would like to capture video of the speaker and video of his slides.

Optimally, I would like to hook up two recording devices, hit record on one program, then the program will record a video stream for each device. When I am done recording I would like to hit stop once on the program and then I would have two videos that are the same length and are basically synchronized. Later I would like the same benefit in editing for simple functions like trimming.

Is there such a program available? Prefer windows but open to other options.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways of doing this... really depends on the cameras you are shooting on & budget.  On set we sometimes use a piece of software called Qtake, which can record two video feeds from an HDSDI source, and play them back immediately, but it's really pricey.  Other ways to do it would be to use a HDSDI trigger to set both devices in to record mode.  Another way is to just make sure your TimeCode is in sync. What cameras are you planning on using?  If you are using Canon 5DII/7D's etc you could use the magiclantern hack and get a trigger record going, see the link below, then the files would correspond and sync up pretty well by the looks.

http://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=1088.0

Comment: Sony HDR-FX7. I take the iLink out into a firewire card and record in sony vegas pro. For slides I use epiphan vga to usb and record in epiphan capture tool, which is not very good.